# Very strange git behavior when merging old branch into develop

Tags: git

Basically, I'm merging an old commit into the develop branch, there were conflicts, and as I was fixing the conflicts, I noticed I was missing several files from my working directory that I created after the most recent common ancestor. Here is what my history looked like before the merge:
[image]

And here is what it looked like after:
[image]

Although, I noticed that there isn't an explicit dashed line that connects `E` to `Head` in the `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` output, but I think that's just because I haven't committed the merge yet... Now, I'm thinking that I don't see the new files because I haven't committed the merge yet, I'll check to see if that's the behavior.

But here's what I've learned thus far: after the merge, there's clearly code in `B`, that wasn't in `D's` branch, that is in `Head`, and yet the new files I added in `B` are not in `Head`.

Any idea why my new files aren't shown in the working tree during the merge?

Comment: Where are you looking for the missing files? If they are not displayed in the output of `git status` then it's probably normal (it depends in what commit you created them and what is the current branch). But if you don't have it in the working tree then you have a problem.

Comment: @axiac they're not in the working tree during the merge. as in, there were conflicts and as i'm fixing the conflicts i noticed that several files were missing. i haven't committed the merge yet

Comment: Committing doesn't change the content of the working tree. It just registers the current status of the working tree in the repository history.

Comment: When you are in the middle of a merge, there's no new commit to view. Some viewers (like gitk) fake one up; `git log` doesn't. Meanwhile `git diff` also behaves differently, showing *combined diffs*, which I always find a bit annoying.

Comment: Could it be that the files were present in the common ancestor, but were deleted in D?

Comment: were the files in E and other intermediate commits? where exactly do they disappear?

Comment: Can you post the command you used to merge? Which branch did you merge into which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was with how `XCode 8.2` determines which files are present and which are not. It's not enough for a file to be present in my project directory in `Finder`, in order for `XCode` to acknowledge the existence of a file, an explicit reference has  to be created for it by either dragging and dropping the file into the project directory in `XCode`, or right clicking somewhere in the project directory in `XCode` and adding a new file.

The problem was I assumed that the files in my project directory in `XCode` accurately reflected what files were in my project directory on disk.

The solution was simply to recreate the references to the missing files in `XCode`.